# how to access .db schema file in jar file

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jar, netbeans-7

I'm using netbeans for my project and i stored my key.db schema file in src folder. (where iused SQLite concept) the program works fine when executed from net beans. but shows the following exception when jarfile is executed.

```
String sDriverName = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
Class.forName(sDriverName);
try {
URL url = insert.class.getResource("key.db");
String sTempDb = url.getPath();
System.out.println(sTempDb);
String sJdbc = "jdbc:sqlite";
String sDbUrl = sJdbc + ":" + sTempDb;
int iTimeout = 30;    
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sDbUrl);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.setQueryTimeout(iTimeout);
System.out.println(GetBoard.number());
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(id) from list");
if(rs.next()){
    if(rs.getInt(1)>1){
        ResultSet mbtest=stmt.executeQuery("select motherboard from list where motherboard='"+GetBoard.number()+"'");
        if(mbtest.next())
            ;//okay
        else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This version of Smart eDocT Software is not original. "
                + "\n please contact sicsi to getFull version.");
    }
    else{
        int idv;
        ResultSet getid=stmt.executeQuery("select max(id) from list");
        if(getid.next()){
            idv=getid.getInt(1)+1;
        }
        else{
            idv=1;
        }
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into list values("+idv+",'"+GetBoard.number()+"')");
    }
}
rs.close();
stmt.close(); 
conn.close();}
```

and the exception is :

```
java.sql.SQLException: path to 'file:/D:/security/store/SCHEDULAR.jar!/key.db': 'C:\\file:' does not exist
    at org.sqlite.Conn.open(Conn.java:103)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.<init>(Conn.java:57)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:77)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at insert.main(insert.java:26)
```

please help to solve this problem and excuss if question is absurd

Comment: please answer my question. waiting for the solution from last 19hrs

Comment: nobody has the knowledge to answer my question even though it was not absurd. useless website this is

Answer (score 0):

Even if @prathima's comments to his question isn't exectly motivating anyone to answer:

Have a look at

[Use SQLite db file in JAR](http://www.shoaibinamdar.in/blog/?p=313)

Just don't forget to put the dbfile in the jar manually, because this code does not create a db file itself. If I find out how to let the db file be created automatically, I'll post it.